# Entity Framework with mapping table adding duplicate entries

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two tables customer and products with many to many relationship which I handle with mapping table called customerproductmap. I then created entity framework model from this database.

This is what I have for onmodelcreation for the customer:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
            .HasMany(e => e.products)
            .WithMany(e => e.customers)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("customerproductMap").MapLeftKey("customerId").MapRightKey("productId"));
```

When I add new data using Context as follows, I see that duplicate entries are being added to customer. The json data I get from the client has parent object with multiple customers. Each customer can have multiple products mapped to it, but these products might have been already added by the previous customer. For e.g. customer1-> products1 and product2 and customer2->Product1. This results in addition of Product1 twice and then these are mapped in the mapping table.

What I want is Product1 is added only once and then mapped to customer1 and customer2 since it’s the same Product. How can I achieve this?

```
using (var context = new DbEntity())
        {
            context.ParentObject.Add(GetEntityFromClientData((clientdata)));
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                .. processing of exception message
           }
        }
```

I am new to entity framework, so it might be a simple thing I am missing.

**EDIT:**
Here is what GetEntityFromClientData does (the relevant parts). You see that I am mapping product1 and product2 to customer1 and product1 to customer2. Then add the region to the database. If I dont then how will I map customer2 to product1.

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
        foreach (var clientCustomer in clientData.Customers)
        {
            var q = from o in clientCustomer.Products
                    select new Product()
                    {
                        ..basic initialization,
                    };

            var customer = new Customer()
            {
                Name = clientCustomer.Name,
                Products = q.ToArray(),
                CustomerId = clientCustomer.Id,
            };

            customers.Add(customer);
        }

        var customerLocation = new CustomerLocation ()
        {
            city = clientData.City,
            Customers= customers.ToArray(),
        };

        var customerLocations = new CustomerLocation []
        {
            customerLocation
        };

        var region = new Region()
        {
            CustomerLocations = customerLocations,
        };

        return region;
```

Comment: we need to see what `GetEntityfromClientData(...)` does

Comment: The only reason duplicate data would be getting added is if you are doing something to add the duplicate data. Are you adding the same Product/Customer multiple times without checking if it's already there? Sounds like you need a business validation to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Do all objects have to be added as new objects. For example, aren't there any pre-existing products that should be added to `customer.Products`?

Comment: Products table and customers table are both empty and will get populated as I add more and more data from clients. So in the process of adding these data I want to make sure I don't add duplicate products.